# looking for files in project folder not in the debug/release folder

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, directory

I'm coding some modern OpenGL which requires external files for the shaders. At this moment, I'm providing the full path of the file inside my application, however, I need to force Qt Creator to look for the files inside the project folder.

[image]

As you can see from the perceding image, the files are in the project folder and have been added as `DISTFILES` in `.pro` file, however, Qt Creator doesn't search for the files in the project folder. Is there any convenient approach to this problem rather than providing the entire the path as follows.

```
 m_program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, "D:\\to the file\\vertexShaderSource.vs");
 m_program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, "D:\\to the file\\fragmentShaderSource.fs");
```

Comment: maybe adding this files to resources file can help?

Comment: @tty6, it did the trick. thanks.